# Is it wrong to miss Jummah on Friday due to school?

Tags: jumuah

I'm a freshman in high-school, I'm allowed to pray Duhr prayers in school and I do, but I'm unable to attend the Friday prayers since I can't leave the school building.

I came across this hadith:

> Narated By Al-Ja'd ad-Damri : The Prophet (pbuh) said: He who leaves the Friday prayer (continuously) for three Friday on account of slackness, Allah will print a stamp on his heart.
>   - Abu Dawud (Book 2, Hadith 1047)

I understand the importance of Friday prayer

Is it wrong for me to miss Jummah on Friday due to school?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my school the brothers have worked around this problem by setting up a jummah khutba with a few brothers. The most knowledgable of us gives a short khutba, and then leads the prayer, as per usual. You have stated you pray at school already so you can pray jummah prayer with no problem inshAllah, provided you can get a congregation.

> O you who have believed, when [the adhan] is called for the prayer on the day of Jumu'ah [Friday], then proceed to the remembrance of Allah and leave trade. That is better for you, if you only knew. [Quran surat-al Jumah 62/9](http://quran.com/62/9)

Answer (score 2):

The hadeeth state that

> The Prophet (pbuh) said: He who leaves the Friday prayer
>   (continuously) for **three Friday on account of slackness**, Allah will
>   print a stamp on his heart.

Note that The Prophet is talking about being careless, and sure you are not so.

In school you have no ability to attend the jummah on Fridays, this is not slackness. Indeed Prophet is talking about those who have free time and nothing force him to not attend the jummah on Fridays.

You are in safe side bro.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't try to accomplish the jummah prayer task, it'll be a sin, but if you try and then are unable to do something or anything then your intention is clear and Allah understands it better than you.

If you have any muslim friends then you can offer the jummah prayer in congregation, with the one who leads in prayer sitting before the jamat and saying a khutba (you can do a mini lecture on any topic concerning islam, e.g. what are bad deeds and how to avoid them....) and then you can offer the salah in congregation.
For the above said you require normally 2 persons. I would recommend 3+